# Reduce function extra bracket meaning - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function:

```
function ross(array) {
  return array.map(function(data) {
   return data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
      obj[item[0]] = item[1];
      return obj;
    }, {});
  });
}
ross(array);
```

Basically this code converts the 3 dimensional array to an array of object. I want to focus on this part:

```
return data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
      obj[item[0]] = item[1];
      return obj;
    }, {});
```

Under the `return obj`, you'll see another extra `{}` brackets beside the comma (,). Not sure what it really does if it's a callback or what. But I tried to played with it by changing it to `[]`,  and it's actually changing the output into two dimensional array.

Anyone out there who could explain what the extra bracket does?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? It tells you exactly what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Those `{}` define an empty object. The second argument to `reduce` is a seed value for the accumulator that's passed to your callback. So that `{}` is defining what your callback sees as `obj` on the first call (and all subsequent calls, because it returns `obj`).

That code is functionally identical to:

```
var obj = {};
data.forEach(function(item) {
  obj[item[0]] = item[1];
});
return obj;
```

`reduce` is just being used (some would say *ab*used, since the accumulator never changes; but it's really common) to make that one outermost statement rather than three.

Comment: My brain is not taking it, can you try to explain it line by line for me if its possible to get some examples? I am sorry I really want to understand what it does.

Comment: *reduce* wouldn't need to be used this way if *forEach* could be set to return a caller–defined value instead of *undefined*, something like `array.forEach(callbackfn, thisArg, accumulator)` and, if supplied, it could be the fourth argument passed to *callbackfn*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) "The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value."

The second parameter is the initial value of the accumulator, which comes into your function as the parameter `obj`.   If you do not specify an accumulator the default is the first element from the array that reduce is invoked on.

Comment: That first sentence from MDN is incomprehensible unless you know how *reduce* works, there must be a better way to say it. :-/